# rails generate --h does not show its documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run rails generate --help in stead of showing the documentation, the console outputs these:

```
/home/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
/home/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant POP
/home/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant POPSession
/home/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant POP3Session
/home/ab/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
/home/ab/finalcrowd/config/environments/development.rb:29: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
Usage: rails [options]
    -p, --port=port
```

This is strange since I was able to run rails generate --help before.
I tried with rails g -h, rails g --help, rails generate -h but it's still the same.
However, rails --help works fine.

EDIT: After using git bisect suggested by phoet, I found that the cause of this problem may come from the thin server since I added two gems thin and private_pub. That's why it kept telling me about adding --port parameter.

Answer (score 2):

running `rails generate --help` should work fine.

if you are using a scm like git, you could use git bisect to find out which commit broke this command. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git

i think that some gem/plugin causes troubles with your rails project. it looks like everything gets loaded twice.

are you sure you are running the right command in the right directory?

Comment: Thank you for introduce git bisect. It is truely a powerful tool. I have edited my question with new information.